# Angular 10 Upgrade and HTTPClient request properties can no longer be set

Tags: angular, header, httpclient, upgrade

Ok, I've tried vairous things now but I'm lost so here it goes.
In my Angular project, I'm trying to upgrade, fine until I've gone from 9 to 10.

My requests through the HttpClient are now failing. I have a base class that adds the token header to all requests for Auth and anything else that is passed in as below:

```
export interface IApiCallerOptions {
    headers?: HttpHeaders;
    params?: HttpParams;
    observe?: 'response' | 'body' | 'events';
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}

private _addAuthHeaderToOptions(options: IApiCallerOptions) {
    var moo = Object.assign({}, options, {
      headers: (options.headers || new HttpHeaders())
      .append('authorization', `bearer ${this._apiLocations.token}`)
    });
    console.log(moo);
    return moo;
  }

get<T>(apiName: ApiNames, apiResource: string, options: IApiCallerOptions = {responseType: 'json'}): Observable<T> {
    const url = this._buildUrl(apiName, apiResource);

    const ops = this._addAuthHeaderToOptions(options);
    var  moo = this._httpClient.get<T>(url, ops);

    return moo;
  }
```

This no longer works and I get the error:

> Overload 1 of 15, '(url: string, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders | {
> [header: string]:  string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?:
> HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?:
> boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }):
> Observable<...>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'IApiCallerOptions & { headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to  parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders |
> { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe: "events"; params?:
> HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?:
> boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boolean; }'.

I feel I have horse blinders on at this point, can someone confirm why I can assign the params to an object as I did before and have it passed into the request??

Comment: It doesn't work because your custom type doesn't match the relevant overloads. But you should just write an interceptor to add the header: https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Seems so long as the types arent interpreted so tightly then its fine again, as the strucuture is correct and no different from before the upgrade.

Just add 'as Object' to the Object.assign to prevent that strong coupling and its compiling and running fine again.